# Python - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'xyz'

Tags: python

I have the following code snippet:

```
for image_name in images:
    img_id = int(image_name.split('.')[0])
    img = skimage.io.imread(os.path.join(train_data_path, image_name))
    img = np.array([img])
```

And getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_original.py", line 99, in <module>
    create_test_data()
  File "data_original.py", line 74, in create_test_data
    img_id = int(image_name.split('.')[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ISIC_1000'
```

I tried replacing `int` by `float`, but got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_original.py", line 97, in <module>
    create_test_data()
  File "data_original.py", line 72, in create_test_data
    img_id = float(image_name.split('.')[0])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ISIC_1000'
```

How can I solve the above issue?

Thanks.

Comment: 'ISIC_1000' isn't an integer. Either you need to store this as a string or strip out 'ISIC_'

Comment: What you are feeding into `int()` or `float()`is not convertible into an integer or float.

Comment: You are trying to convert string `"ISIC_1000"` to a number, and it simply isn't a number.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that argument passed to `int()` is convertable to number, suppose: `image_name.split('.')[0]` returns a sting containing letters (a-Z) or some other chars which are not number (for example: 'xyz' or 'ISIC_1000').

You can also use `try/except`.